# Como faço o link no gcc de uma biblioteca C criada por min?

Tags: c

Criei uma simples biblioteca na linguagem C , exemplo.h e exemplo.c, e a inclui em um terceiro código chamado (codigo.c).

Só que ao compilar este terceiro código:

gcc codigo.c -o codigo.out

Deu erro de undefined reference to :"nome das funções que usei"

Logo vi que precisava fazer o link da biblioteca mas?

Como faço o link no gcc de uma biblioteca criada por mim?

PS: uso linux (raspbian)

Comment: Não é só compilar a biblioteca junto? `gcc -o codigo.out codigo.c exemplo.c` - https://stackoverflow.com/q/15441877

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa adicioná-las ao arquivo principal apenas. Por exemplo:

```c
// Bibliotecas "built-in"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// Suas bibliotecas (O endereço para cada uma)
#include "tool/args/options.c"
#include "tool/args/validation.c"
#include "tool/define/type.c"
#include "tool/file/write-to-file.c"
```